# Python multiprocessing- write the results in the same file

Tags: python, sqlite, multiprocessing

I have a simple function that writes the output of some calculations in a sqlite table. I would like to use this function in parallel using multi-processing in Python. My specific question is how to avoid conflict when each process tries to write its result into the same table? Running the code gives me this error: sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked.

```
import sqlite3
from multiprocessing import Pool

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE table_1 (id int,output int)")

def write_to_file(a_tuple):
    index = a_tuple[0]
    input = a_tuple[1]
    output = input + 1
    c.execute('INSERT INTO table_1 (id, output)' 'VALUES (?,?)', (index,output))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool()
    results = p.map(write_to_file, [(1,10),(2,11),(3,13),(4,14)])
    p.close()
    p.join()

Traceback (most recent call last):
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Comment: You cannot spawn concurrent processes that write to the exact same table at the exact same time. Hence the `SQLITE_BUSY` error that returns "database is locked". Each process needs to finish before another one starts, which unfortunately means no multiprocessing for this purpose.

Comment: A workaround if the calculations are expensive:  run a single process that writes to the database, running an infinite loop that pulls the data to write from a `multiprocessing.Queue`.  Other processes put descriptions of what to write on the `Queue`.  But whether that's a net win overall can't be guessed from the little you've revealed ;-)

Comment: This is a [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications and the link. Since the calculations are expensive and the results produced are very big, I think it would be better to save the results of every process in a separate database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a `Pool` is a good idea.

I see three possible solutions to this problem.

First, instead of having the pool worker trying to insert data into the database, let the worker return the data to the parent process.

In the parent process, use `imap_unordered` instead of `map`.
This is an iterable that starts providing values as soon as they become available. The parent can than insert the data into the database.

This will *serialize* the access to the database, preventing the problem.

This solution would be preferred if the data to be inserted into the database is relatively small, but updates happen very often. So if it takes the same or more time to update the database than to calculate the data.

---

Second, you could use a `Lock`. A worker should then

- acquire the lock,
- open the database,
- insert the values,
- close the database,
- release the lock.

This will avoid the overhead of sending the data to the parent process. But instead you may have workers stalling waiting to write their data into a database.

This would be a preferred solution if the amount of data to be inserted is *large* but it takes much longer to calculate the data than to insert it into the database.

---

Third, you could have each worker write to its own database, and merge them afterwards. You can do this [directly in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18713032/1219295) or even [in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11653654/1219295). Although with a large amount of data I'm not sure if the latter has advantages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The data I need to read in the real function are around 20 million numbers and I would like to write the same amount of data to the database after the calculations. I will try to write the results of each process to a different database and later combine them.

Comment: @BehzadJamali I also thought about that but didn't add it to the answer because I was not sure what the right use-case was for that. I've added it now.

Answer (score 1):

The database is locked to protect your data from corruption.

I believe you cannot have many processes accessing the same database at the same time, at least NOT with

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
```

If each process must access the database, you should consider closing at least the `cursor` object `c` (and, perhaps less strictly, the `connect` object `conn`) within each process and reopen it when the process needs it again.  Somehow, the other processes need to wait for the current one to release the lock before another process can acquire the lock. (There are many ways to achieved the waiting).

Answer (score 1):

Setting the [`isolation_level`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) to [`'EXCLUSIVE'`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions) fixed it for me:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db', isolation_level='EXCLUSIVE')
```

Comment: With the example given in the question, `isolation_level='EXCLUSIVE'` doesn't work for me but `isolation_level=None` does.